# ASP.NET 5 MVC (Visual Studio 2015): a keyword called Inject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've just installed visual studio 2015 and played around the ASP.NET 5 template (MVC) and I saw a keyword called `inject` that has been used in the view. Is it for dependency injection, and if yes how does it work? Assuming the below code:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;
    private static bool _databaseChecked;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ISmsSender smsSender,
        ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _smsSender = smsSender;
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
  ...
  }
```

The login view has an inject keyword like:

```
@model LoginViewModel
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager

@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";

 }
```

However, I don't see this in other views, and there's no trace of Ninject nor Unity in the app. What is this? a new amazing feature?

Comment: Its a new feature in MVC-6. Refer [this article](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc) for more detail

Comment: You are right, it just injects services into your views. No need for Ninject, Unity etc. ASP.NET 5 has dependency injection built in to it. The other views did not need to use any injected object, so they don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net 5 comes with built-in dependency injection and many features around it. In your example you are injecting an instance of `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` named `SignInManager` into the razor view.

You can now use it just like you'd normally use the Model property: `@SignInManager.Method()`

See this article for more information: http://blog.tomasjansson.com/asp-net-5-ioc-and-dependency-injection/